# Appending to list in Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a more elegant way to write this code?

What I am doing: I have keys and dates. There can be a number of dates assigned to a key and so I am creating a dictionary of lists of dates to represent this. The following code works fine, but I was hoping for a more elegant and Pythonic method.

```
dates_dict = dict() 
for key,  date in cur:
    if key in dates_dict:
        dates_dict[key].append(date)
    else:
        dates_dict[key] = [date]
```

I was expecting the below to work, but I keep getting a NoneType has no attribute append error.

```
dates_dict = dict() 
for key,  date in cur:
    dates_dict[key] = dates_dict.get(key, []).append(date)
```

This probably has something to do with the fact that

```
print([].append(1)) 
None
```

but why?

Comment: You should look into [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: you may try using extend() instead of append()

Comment: `for key,  date in cur:` - what is `cur` ?

Comment: @Mawg this was a while ago, but I was probably using a cursor object associated with Python's sqlite3 library.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None`, since it is an in-place operation and you are assigning it back to `dates_dict[key]`. So, the next time when you do `dates_dict.get(key, []).append` you are actually doing `None.append`. That is why it is failing. Instead, you can simply do

```
dates_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(date)
```

But, we have [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this purpose only. You can do something like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
dates_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, date in cur:
    dates_dict[key].append(date)
```

This will create a new list object, if the `key` is not found in the dictionary.

**Note:** Since the `defaultdict` will create a new list if the key is not found in the dictionary, this will have unintented side-effects. For example, if you simply want to retrieve a value for the key, which is not there, it will create a new list and return it.

Comment: @chepner: Note that `__missing__()` is not called for any operations besides `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using `default_factory` i.e., `key in dates_dict` and `dates_dict.get(key)` work as expected

Comment: Just as a followup. I ended up using setdefault as this git me exactly what I wanted without an extra import. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your explanation of why `[].append` returns `None` doesn't make sense to me. If you are assigning or printing it immediately, why does it matter it is an in-place operation? Why would `dates_dict.get(key, []).append` yield `None` unless `dates_dict[key] == None`?

Comment: Exactly! In one of the iterations, the result of append is stored against the key and the same is retrieved with get and appended. But this time it's not a list but None

Comment: What's the advantage of using defaultdict over setdefault ?

Answer (score 39):

> Is there a more elegant way to write this code?

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dates_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, date in cur:
    dates_dict[key].append(date)
```

Comment: When I try `for key, date_list in dates_dict:`, I get `error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @Mawg look at the code in the answer. I don't see your example there.

Comment: @Axl Look at the code in the answer and in the comment. Do you see a difference? (note:  `cur` is not the same as `dates_dict` — they are different objects)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Because it's should be `for key, date_list in dates_dict.items():`

Comment: @Takamura: wrong. `cur` is the input. `dates_dict` is for the result. It is empty in the beginning. There is no point to iterate over it. The code in the answer is correct as is.

Comment: I'm not talking about the code in the answer, I think what @Mawg tried was after running the code in the answer

Answer (score 7):

`dates_dict[key] = dates_dict.get(key, []).append(date)` sets   `dates_dict[key]` to `None` as `list.append` returns `None`.

```
In [5]: l = [1,2,3]

In [6]: var = l.append(3)

In [7]: print var
None
```

You should use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections
dates_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. As there is no value returned. It will return None as default. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelMurphy, using defaultdict will be the most efficient way to do what you want