# Python/Flask add key to inner dictionary

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to construct a dictionary with a list of IDs, which will be used as the response from an API. The dict will be used to generate a JSON response.

I am trying to append a list of IDs that have been affected by the request, but am experiencing an error shown below the code.

I have the following code:

```
data = {"data" : { "message" : "UPDATED TICKETS SUCCESSFULLY", "status" : 200}}
data['data'].append({"child_ids" : child_sr_ids})
```

The error that I am getting is: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

This seems to contradict other sources that I have read such as this: [Appending to list in Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367812/appending-to-list-in-python-dictionary)

I am sure I'm doing something simple wrong but I can't work it out. Would appreciate some direction.

edit: title has been changed to better reflect the correct terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data["data"]` is not a list. It is a dictionary. There isn't a single list in your code. I think what you want to do here is:

`data["data"]["child_ids"] = child_sr_ids`

Answer (score 1):

You're not appending to a list, you're adding a key to the inner dictionary. What you're looking for is:

```
data['data']['child_ids'] = child_sr_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try the line below or use dict update

```
data["new key"] = "some new entry"
```