# Python: updating a list as a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have lists as values of a dictionary and want to ability to append to those list when there is a match in key.

I understand I can do it when the list is predefined as follows:

```
hashmap = {}
k = [1,2,3]
val = ['a','b','c']
for i in k:
    hashmap[i]= val
for j in hashmap.keys():
    print(hashmap[j])
```

But what if the contents of the val list is not defined. How do I declare it runtime and append to those list?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If val is not defined, how do you expect to use `val`? Also note, you do not have *lists* here, you have a **single list**.

Comment: Kind of sounds like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367812/appending-to-list-in-python-dictionary

Comment: @Orenshi aha, yes, possibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` to create the list if it doesn't exist:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
dd['a'].append(1)  # create the list if it doesn't exist
print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1]})
```