# add a list to a dictionary key within a for loop with an undefined key

Tags: python

I'm collating some data into a dictionary, and I wonder if there is a better method to work with dictionaries

Lets assume I have a dictionary called `dict_` and I initialise it as so

```
dict_ = {}
```

now I have an object that I want to iterate over and add into my dictionary.

```
for item in iterable:
   dict_[key_a] = item.data
```

this works if there is only one item.data to add to the key but what if I have an array?

I know I could do this

```
dict_[key_a] = []
for item in iterable:
    dict_[key_a] = [item.data]
```

but I wonder if there is a method where I could skip `dict_[key_a] = []` to keep my code more concise?

using `dict_['key_a'].append(item.data)` results in a error, and rightly so.

my expected output would be

```
print(dict_)
{'key_a' : ['foo','bar']}
```

Happy Holidays to you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to list in Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367812/appending-to-list-in-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one idiomatic way, using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for pre-initializing keys with empty lists as default values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_ = defaultdict(list)

for item in iterable:
   dict_[key_a].append(item.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another possibility for funsies, using the unpack operator (edited to include switch ladder):

```py
for item in iterable:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        dict_[key_a] = item.data
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        dict_[key_a] = [*item.data]
    ...
```